# URL rewrite rule only for a type of request

Tags: apache

Is there any way to create a htaccess url rewrite rule only for DELETE or PUT http requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. It would be easier if you posted your RewriteRule. All you need to add is the following conditions to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =DELETE [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =PUT
```

Which means, operate the RewriteRule only when the request method is DELETE OR PUT.